# Web browsing with Chrome unexpectedly passes through a Google proxy

Tags: networking, google-chrome, proxy

For some reason, I'm not able to post in some sites because I'm being detected as from another country. Then, I tested "what is my public IP" in many of those sites that provides this service. In some of them, they showed my actual public Ip but in some others it showed this IP which seems to be from google `66.249.88.109`.

At `ipleak.com` and the site which I got blocked from posting, it showed that my IP was this one that I just quoted with domain name `google-proxy-66-249-88-109.google.com`. Now, at `ipleak.net` for example it showed my actual public IP and even quoted my ISP correctly.

What can be going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Are you using Chrome's **[Data Saver](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392284?hl=en)** feature?

- Data Saver tunnels data through a Google-operated proxy which provides data compression to reduce data usage. For privacy, HTTPS sites and incognito (private) tabs do not go through the proxy. This might explain the issue you're experiencing.
- [ipleak.com](http://www.ipleak.com) is unencrypted HTTP and passes through the proxy while [ipleak.net](https://www.ipleak.net) is HTTPS and therefore bypasses the proxy.